# How to define the Array Size in variable

Tags: vba, excel

my array size is decided by the some other function. but when i tried to define the size of the array using the variable i am getting the error "Constant Expression Required"

i would like define the size of the array

```
Option Explicit
Sub Abcd()
    Dim n_variables As Integer
    n_variables = def()
    MsgBox "n_variables" & n_variables
    Dim abc(1 To n_variables) As Integer  
End Sub
Function def()
    def = 100
End Function
```

is there any way i can define the array size in variable format?
Any one help me please.

Comment: You can always use `Redim` to change array size.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Redim` statement:

```
Dim n_variables As Integer
n_variables = def()
MsgBox "n_variables" & n_variables
Dim abc() As Integer  
Redim abc(1 To n_variables) As Integer
```